# Syntax to insert elements into multimap<string, vector<pair<string, int>>>

Tags: c++, vector, syntax, multimap, std-pair

My question is how to insert some element into multimap of the form

```
multimap<string, vector<pair<string, int>>> someMap; //std skipped to simplify
```

I tried different syntaxes and i think the closest one may be this one

```
someMap.insert(pair<string,vector<pair<string, int>>>(someString1, vector<pair<string, int>> { pair<string, int> (someString2, someInt) }));
```

Unfortunately it is not working. Any tips??

Comment: Use [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) to avoid typing and misspelling redundant type information.

Comment: @Csq I added comment that i skipped all std:: to simplify a code a little bit. Anyway thanks for the tip

Comment: Not working... how? Error? Warning? Crash? Don't keep us in suspense.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the syntax isn't correct. That's the last version I tried someMap.insert( {someString1,  vector<pair<string, int> ( {someString2, someInt} ) } ); and the error i got:

Comment: @JonathanPotter error: temporary of non-literal type ‘std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>’ in a constant expression
     family.insert( {name,  vector<pair<string, int> ( {pair<string, int>(children_name, age)} ) } );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the first pair is wrong

```
pair<string,vector<string, int>>
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

anyway I suggest:

```
multimap<string, vector<pair<string, int>>> someMap;
vector<pair<string,int>> obj;
someMap.insert(make_pair("hello", obj));
```

or if you insist with that syntax (verbose-mode):

```
  multimap<string, vector<pair<string, int>>> someMap;
  string someString2 = "hello";
  string someString1 = "world";
  int someInt = 42;
  someMap.insert(pair<string,vector<pair<string, int>>>(someString1, vector<pair<string, int>> { pair<string, int> (someString2, someInt) }));
```

this requires C++11.

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo, obviously it should be pair<string,vector<pair<string, int>>>

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I have to check where i made a typo because i tried very similar code at the beginning. Thank you for you time.

Comment: hmmm, the funny part is that after i fixed that typo my code looks the same as yours if you check the first post, but i didn't realized it until i compared both :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    typedef std::pair<std::string, int> value_type;
    std::multimap<std::string, std::vector<value_type>> m; 

    m.insert( { "A", std::vector<value_type>( 1, { "A", 'A' } ) } );

    return 0;
}
```

Or another example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    typedef std::pair<std::string, int> value_type;
    std::multimap<std::string, std::vector<value_type>> m; 

    auto it = m.insert( { "A", std::vector<value_type>( 1, { "A", 'A' } ) } );

    for ( char c = 'B'; c <= 'Z'; ++c )
    {
        const char s[] = { c, '\0' };

        it->second.push_back( { s, c } );
    }

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( const auto &p : it->second )
    {
        std::cout << "{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "} ";
        if ( ++i % 7 == 0 ) std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
{A, 65} {B, 66} {C, 67} {D, 68} {E, 69} {F, 70} {G, 71} 
{H, 72} {I, 73} {J, 74} {K, 75} {L, 76} {M, 77} {N, 78} 
{O, 79} {P, 80} {Q, 81} {R, 82} {S, 83} {T, 84} {U, 85} 
{V, 86} {W, 87} {X, 88} {Y, 89} {Z, 90}
```

Comment: std::vector<value_type>( 1, { "A", 'A' } it should be without that 1 because we are storing pairs of string and int. I already tried it but it doesn't work(1 mean first solution)

Comment: @user3119781 All works. Try it at www.ideone.com. The constructor of std::vector requires two arguments.

Comment: Hmmm, i tried again by just copying your code into mine and it's working :), my apologies. I need to try a bug in my code because i tried to adjust it to yours but i skipped that1 in the constructor. Could you try to explain that additional argument or send soome link to read about it, i thought that as usual we can use normal initializer list or something similar.

Comment: @user3119781 Here is the declaration of the vector constructor vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());

Comment: Apparently there are to solutions, i think i made a little typo and that's why my code wasn't working, but thanks for your help it is good to know there are always different solutions :)